# Change in Maven project will update automatically?

Tags: git, maven, continuous-integration, devops

do changes we make in maven project (in eclipse) get updated in git local repo automatically?

Eclipse IDE

Comment: No, right click on the project then Maven->Update Project, alt-F5 is the shortcut.

Comment: It will get updated inside the eclipse only right? but when we try checking the git local repo using "git status" it is showing as Modified if we do change the code in the project

Comment: any changes made in Eclipse will not be transferred to a repository until they are 'pushed' from the command line, or synchronized from eclipse. Think of eclipse as an editor of the code.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554213/what-exactly-does-maven-update-project-do-in-eclipse gives a brief explanation about maven update in eclipse and No, maven update won't push the code into git! until you commit and push

Comment: Did you clear up your doubts?